# php shape recognition in images

Tags: php

I want to detect a certain shape in an photo using PHP. Take a look at the following photo of my girlfriend.

[image: My girlfriend]

This photo has a few black corners in it. I would like to detect those corners and cut out whats in side of it. (Like in the example image above).

I'd like to do this in PHP without the use of any 3rd party library.

Any idea how to do this and what algorithms i can use to detect (basic?) shapes like that?

Comment: You want to recognize only faces or...?

Comment: What you could try though is to scan through every pixel of the image and use the black areas (preferably 1x1 px each) as markers, such as: Scan -> First marker, that is the top left corner -> Keep scanning -> Next marker, this is the top right corner. From there you only scan the image within these two coordinates downwards until you end at the last marker in the down left corner. As you already have the coordinates you do some basic math to figure out the proportions of the image. From there you could simply crop the image of your fake girlfriend and assign it a new name.

Comment: @Alix No, it can be anything. I just need to detect the markers (the black corners) and get what ever is inside of those markers. In this case it's a face, but it could be a picture of anything.


I can't use 1px markers, because eventually i need to detect this from an image taken with a phone camera or webcam. That's why the shape recognition is important.

Comment: its not face recognition its pattern recognition and very basic means easy.

Comment: Do you have control over the markers used, and is it always the same marker? You'll be iterating over all pixels to some extent, but choice and knowledge of the exact marker shapes can give you some big optimizations. Your example, for instance, uses 6px wide black lines, so you can could scan in a 6px grid looking for the necessary congregations of black pixels. Then go finer to get the exact boundaries, and once you find a marker you can stop searching certain areas that can't possibly fall on the inside of that marker.

Comment: Alyson Hannigan? i think may be not.

Comment: As far as I know, OpenCV is the most advanced openly available solution for this: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easy though it may require intensive computing on server side.

1. Its pattern recognition and very basic pattern.
2. Also we have four different shapes to detect.
3. Considering the solid and predefined color.
4. Considering the shapes will have constant dimensions.

It can be achieved by

1. Reading all pixels one by one from top-left to bottom right corner of image.
2. Constructing the first (top-left) and second (top-right) shape by comparing encountered pixels of predefined color with the predefined dimensions of shapes respectively.
3. Same steps for 3rd and fourth shapes.
4. Now if all four or any three or any two (top-left and bottom-right) or ( top-right and bottom-left ) shapes are detected, we can crop the required image.

My answer my look vague but the only real answer to is code.